# Vue: How to change a button's text while a keyboard modifier is held?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modifier-key

Using Vue, I am trying to make a button change its behavior when the Shift key is held.
It was pretty easy to change the behavior of the `click` event as such:

```
@click.exact="goForward"
@click.shift="goBackward"
```

However, I am struggling with changing the text of the button to reflect this behavior. The default text is `Forward`, and I am trying to change it to `Backward` when the Shift key is being held down.

I tried to use `@mouseover.shift` but it's not good enough, because it does not capture the case of `mouse enters the button, then user holds shift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [vue-keypress](https://github.com/lupas/vue-keypress) package:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <button>{{ buttonText }}</button>
    ...
    <Keypress key-event="keydown" :key-code="16" @success="buttonText = 'Backward'" />
    <Keypress key-event="keyup" :key-code="16" @success="buttonText = 'Forward'" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  data: () => ({
    buttonText: 'Forward',
  }),
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good, I'll give it a go. I was really hoping there'd be a way to do it without external packages though

Comment: IF you do not want to bring external package for this work - you can simply attach a `keyup` and `keydown` event handlers to `document` which can update a variable inside the root Vue instance which you can then access by `$root.ShiftActive`